# Easy way to find and replace dynamic values ( {{example}} ) via regex in R

Tags: regex, r

I have some dynamic values obtained from `json` of the format `{{example_value}}`. I have some R code which calculates the actual value. However, the only solution I have found to replace the placeholder with the actual value is very long and ugly.

Does anyone have any neat solutions?

Example of replacing `{{example_value}}` with `5.5`:

```
> gsub( gsub("\\}","\\\\}",gsub("\\{","\\\\{","{{example_value}}")), 
5.5, "{{example_value}}")

[1] "5.5"
```

Another example which explains why I wrote the nested gsub:

```
dictionary = "{{example_value}}"
> gsub( gsub("\\}","\\\\}",gsub("\\{","\\\\{",dictionary)), 
5.5, "{{example_value}}")

[1] "5.5"
```

Typically `dictionary` is a list which contains all the dynamic values I expect to replace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this:

```
gsub("{{example_value}}", "5.5", subject, perl=TRUE);
```

Comment: Thanks, Alex! See you next time. :)

Comment: Hey Alex, I see there's some discussion... in case you need full nested braces instead of a literal, I would use this recursive expression: `{{(?:[^{}]++|(?R))*}}`

Comment: I need a literal because I am reading the curly braces from a dictionary.

Comment: Yeah that's how I understood it, I just offered it because I noticed there was some convo in the comments. :)

Answer (score 1):

While @zx81's suggestion seems most appropriate for a direct replace, You could also work with regular expressions to pull out tags in braces.

```
a<-"The total is {{example}} dollars less"
m <- regexpr("{{([^}]+)}}", a, perl=T)
regmatches(a, m)
# [1] "{{example}}"
```

And then `regmatches` has a nice feature where you can easily replace matches

```
regmatches(a, m) <- 5.5
a
# [1] "The total is 5.5 less"
```

Which is kind of a neat trick.

Comment: @MrFlick or this, `{{(?:[^{}]++|(?R))*}}` to match things like `{{ my {{beautiful}} {{nest {{ :) }}  }} }}`... But from the requirements, it doesn't sound like that's what he wants.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**: Perhaps this may lead you to what you're looking for.

```
re  <- c('{{foo}}', '{{bar}}')
val <- c('5.5',  '1.1')

recurse <- function(pattern, repl, x) {
    for (i in 1:length(pattern))
       x <- gsub(pattern[i], repl[i], x, perl=T)
       x
}

x <- 'I have {{foo}} and {{bar}}'
recurse(re, val, x)

# [1] "I have 5.5 and 1.1"
```

Comment: Hi, while correct, this solution is not appropriate for finding and replacing dynamic values based off a dictionary of existing dynamic values.

Comment: This works for my situation when `x` only has one set of curly braces, but I need to distinguish between them if `x` has multiple different dynamic values.

Comment: How does this match only one set of curly braces?

Comment: This behaviour is unwanted: `> gsub('{{[^}]*}}', '5.5', "{{hmm}} and {{hello}}", perl=T)` gives `[1] "5.5 and 5.5`.

Comment: That is what I will do, and use `lapply` on the `from` vector! :) Thanks!

Comment: oh very good indeed, thanks. This gets around the problem of not being able to apply `gsub` using a vector of `from` and `to` values. The only thing I would do is change the square brackets to double square brackets to allow pattern and replacement to be a list. And use `seq_along(pattern)` instead of `1:length(pattern)`.