# Remove text outside of brackets in R

Tags: regex, r, text

So I have a set of text like below that has brackets around all the named entities, I want to remove the text outside of the brackets and keep all the punctuation. Any thoughts?

```
Sample_Text <- "[PERSON Meredith Vieira] will become the first woman to host [MISC Olympics] primetime coverage on her own when she fills on Friday night for the ailing [PERSON Bob Costas] , who is battling a continuing eye infection. " It 's an honor to fill in for him , " [PERSON Vieira] said on TODAY Friday ."
```

Ideally I would end up with this vector below.

```
Entities <- ([PERSON Meredith Vieira] [MISC Olympics] [PERSON Bob Costas]. [PERSON Vieira].)
```

My first attempt was to grep out the text between two brackets but I wasn't getting the text and my REGEX wasn't working properly. Then I realized I need the punctuation. Here is my REGEX attempt below. Thoughts?

```
grep("\\[.*?\\]", "", d, perl=TRUE)
```

Comment: have a look at MrFlick's answer to this question I asked: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24319930/easy-way-to-find-and-replace-dynamic-values-example-via-regex-in-r . In short, use `regexpr` and `regmatches`, together with your regular expression to match square brackets.

Comment: Alex, thanks for the suggestions of     regexpr and     regmatches! Not exactly appropriate as I really want the text inside the brackets as well as some of the punctuation. I don't want to replace them at all, I want to extract them. Its for an NLP task I have. Thanks though because I didn't know about    regexpr or     regmatches and will probably have an occasion to use them soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the below regex which uses the verb `(*SKIP)(*F)`,

```
> gsub("(?:\\[.*?\\]|\\.)(*SKIP)(*F)|[\\w' ,\\\"]+", " ", Sample_Text, perl=TRUE);
[1] "[PERSON Meredith Vieira] [MISC Olympics] [PERSON Bob Costas] . [PERSON Vieira] ."
```

To remove the leading spaces before `.`,

```
> result <- gsub("(?:\\[.*?\\]|\\.)(*SKIP)(*F)|[\\w' ,\\\"]+", " ", Sample_Text, perl=TRUE);
> result
[1] "[PERSON Meredith Vieira] [MISC Olympics] [PERSON Bob Costas] . [PERSON Vieira] ."
> gsub(" +(?=\\.)", "", result, perl=TRUE);
[1] "[PERSON Meredith Vieira] [MISC Olympics] [PERSON Bob Costas]. [PERSON Vieira]."
```

Comment: Avinash, thanks for the answer! When I run it on the sample text its perfect.